# How to get Sphinx to generate TOC entries for Properties in Pure RST

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have a "pure RST" set of Sphinx files for writing multi-class API documentation. [Here is the start of this project](https://ascom-standards.org/newdocs/index.html), so you can see the structure and directives I am using. It's going well, except that the sidebar and document table of contents for each `.. class::` contains only the `.. method::` members and not the `.. property::` members. You can see my RST source and the results (including the missing `.. property::` entries) via the above [link](https://ascom-standards.org/newdocs/index.html) and the "View page source" links on each, including the `toctree` directives and document structure.

Why is it not generating TOC entries for the properties? What can I do to get a complete list of member TOC entries for each class. Note that he `.. include::` members are marked `:noindex:` so I know why they are not being listed (separate story!).

Comment: I stumbled on a "solution". My `..property::` statements included a data type as `-> int` or whatever. Shot in the dark... Removing this datatype caused the property to appear in the table of contents!! Unless someone shows me the error of my ways, I'll have to go with this.

Comment: There is a `:type:` option on `.. property::`. Does that help? https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#directive-option-py-property-type

Comment: Btw, your output looks a bit strange since the method names in the sidebar (such as `AbortExposure()`) are at the same indentation level as the class name (`ICamera`).

Comment: @mzjn THANK YOU!! `:type:` is what I need. And the indentation, yes, this is another oddity that I am trying to address, but it won't bother me too much. The main thing is that I need the members to all be in the TOC. Thanks again especially for `:type:`

Answer (score 0):

Problem caused by the presence of Python-style datatype hints:

```
.. property:: Foo -> int
```

causes failures of both TOC and permalink, however

```
.. property:: Foo
```

works perfectly. And as @mzjn pointed out in comments,

```
.. property:: Foo
   :type: Integer
```

Produces a typed property which I was looking for, and even better, in a way that is not Pythonic.

Oddly, the presence of type hinting on methods, as in

```
.. method:: DoIt() -> int
```

does not cause errors of TOC or permalinks and renders fine. This is what drove me mad to begin with.